# Question on circular arrangements involving couples.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 4 couples which need to be seated on a round table such that all couples sit together, and in 2 couples the male sits on the right of his partner, and on the left in the other two couples.  How many ways in which is this possible?

I saw this question on an exam. My reasoning is  first consider the 4 couples as 4 units around a circle in 6 ways, and then arrange them in which 2 males are on the left and the other 2 are on the right in 6 ways as LLRR can be arranged in 6 ways. So, the total is 36 ways. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: There's an unwarranted heteronormative assumption here that all couples contain exactly one male. Ideally such assumptions shouldn't be made, but if you do make them, please make them explicitly for your hypothetical scenario and don't write as if the world contained only heterosexual couples.

Comment: Joriki,That is the question that came up in an exam. Learn to read properly then comment.

Comment: Not every one lives in the degenerate west.